# Could I have used a for loop somehow?

Tags: python, tkinter

Just wondering if there is a way to clean this up a little where its a bunch of lines that only changes a little. This is using python 3.4.3, tkinter, and mysql.connector.

```
    Plantname = tk.StringVar()
    self.Plantbox = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=Plantname)
    self.Plantbox.grid(row=0, column=0)

    self.Name = tk.Label(self, text="Name",width=10)
    self.Name.grid(row=1, column=0)

    self.Amount = tk.Label(self, text="Amount",width=10)
    self.Amount.grid(row=1, column=1)

    self.Date = tk.Label(self, text="Date",width=10)
    self.Date.grid(row=1, column=2)

    self.Planting = tk.Label(self, text="Planting #",width=10)
    self.Planting.grid(row=1, column=3)

    self.batch = tk.Label(self, text="batch #",width=10)
    self.batch.grid(row=1, column=4)

    self.Name_2 = tk.Label(self, text="0")
    self.Name_2.grid(row=2, column=0)

    self.Amount_2 = tk.Label(self, text="0")
    self.Amount_2.grid(row=2, column=1)

    self.Date_2 = tk.Label(self, text="0")
    self.Date_2.grid(row=2, column=2)
```

full code:

https://pastebin.com/JPjrtdEg

Comment: If the code is working, you may want to post on [codereview.se], but remember to read their help center and How to ask page before asking, to prevent downvotes.

Comment: Thanks, first time posting to StackOverflow, so unsure where to post what questions.

Comment: (side note (although I didn't downvote): The downvote is not a personal attack on you, it's an indication that the question itself is bad (wrong site, in this case), so don't feel bad about it, just asking good questions instead)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to codereview

Comment: I would also like to add that when you post on Code Review you should post a working example or the complete code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a loop. There's nothing special about tkinter objects that make them any different than any other python object.

```
for col, heading in enumerate(("Name", "Amount", "Date", "Planting #", "batch #")):
    label = tk.Label(self, text=heading, width=10)
    label.grid(row=1, column=col)
```